# Python No module named

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a custom module that I am trying to read from a folder under a hierarchy:

```
> project-source
        /tests
            /provider
             my_provider.py
         settings_mock.py
         __init__.py
```

I am trying to call, from my_provider.py

```
import tests.settings_mock as settings
```

Example from command line:

```
project-source> python tests/provider/my_provider.py
```

Error:

```
... ImportError: No module named settings_mock
```

I keep getting `No module named settings_mock` as error. I have already exported `project_source` path to PYTHONPATH. I have made tests into a package by creating a `__init__.py` file in its root, but no change in the error then.

I can print the `settings_mock.py` attributes when cd'ing project source

```
>>> import tests.settings_mock as settings
>>> print settings.storage_provider
correct storage provider value
```

Is anyone able to point out my mistake here? Thanks!

Comment: You can use relative imports, if your subfolders are packages (i.e. they contain an `__init__.py`): `from .. import settings_mock`

Comment: just add an empty **___init___.py** to your tests directory

Comment: where's the `__init__.py`.

Comment: I have already added __init__py in the folder tests. I now updated the question for clarity.

Comment: where is the main script (the one you're executing) located? It could have something to do with the path.

Comment: It is in my_provider.py (`project-source/tests/provider/my_provider.py`)

Answer (score 1):

You only have one small mistake. To use subfolders, you need `__init__.py`, not `init.py` as you stated in the question. The difference is that `__init__` is a builtin function of python, whereas `init` is not. Having this file in each subfolder tells the pyhon interpreter that the folder is a "package" that needs to be initialized.

**UPDATED:** It should be noted that python usually runs from the current directory that the script is located. If your executable main script is `my_provider.py`, then it's not going to know what to import, since the main script is located in a lower directory than the object it is trying to import. Think of it as a hierarchy. Scripts can only import things that are beneath them. Try separating out the executable from everything else in that file, if there are things that `settings_mock` needs to import.

Comment: Sorry, the formatting of the SO question didn't show but I had written  `__init__.py` (edited the question to show this), so it isn't the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll see if I can reproduce your problem again.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the issue with your setup, while running a main.py in the `project-source` directory that imports the `settings_mock.py`. Where are you running the main.py file from?

Comment: my working directory is `project-source` but the script being run is `project-source/tests/provider/my_provider.py`

Comment: How are you changing the working directory to project-source? Traditionally, the working directory is set to wherever the script is located.

Comment: I just updated my question with what I think may fix the problem. In summary, the executable part of a program/script is usually on the upper-most level of the program, so that it can import anything beneath it that it needs. Please let me know if there are any other issues or if this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I am trying on the command line and on PyCharm. On PyCharm I set "Working directory" to the top folder `project-source`; on the command line I am setting PYTHONPATH to `project-source` (I may be wrong on this bit perhaps)

Comment: On other tests that I am writing, when I import some other folder under `project-source` it works fine. The problem seems to be happening when I try to import from `tests.[something]`. but I don't know what it is...

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on with that single folder, if others with a similar set up are working. I'm going to stick with my original suggestion of moving the main executable to the uppermost directory of the project location.